# Servlet exception using CDI with Jboss Weld

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

Im working on a web application using `JSF 2` and `RichFaces 4`. I use the `ConversationScope` of `CDI` but I have the following exception when I launch the project on `tomcat server 6`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must call associate() before calling activate()
 at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.activate(AbstractConversationContext.java:200)
 at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:108)
 at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:85)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```